# Cant deploy to android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
>   -bootclasspath "C:/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\espma\Desktop\Velux\Velux1.2CPY\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\google\vr\cardboard\R.java" "com\Izstop\veluxvr\R.java" "vr\gvr\platform\unity\R.java"
>   warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>   3 warnings

I'm getting these warnings at home when I try to build my app, but don't get those at the office, using the same settings. I updated my SDK and JDK, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

On Unity :

click on EDIT, then PREFERENCES, EXTERNAL TOOLS and finally you can BROWSE to put the right jdk you had previously downloaded.

Comment: I'm trying to build in Unity3D. Does this work also?